# Move-Item Could not find part of the path DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: powershell

I'm getting the following error with this script: `Move-Item: Could not find part of the path DirectoryNotFoundException`.

```
#<BEGIN_SCRIPT>#
cls
#----- define parameters -----#

#----- define folder where files are located ----#
$MoveFolderLocation ='.\Move_Folder_Input.csv'
$MoveFolderLocation = Read-Host "Where is the folder list file?"
$MoveFolder = Get-Content -path $MoveFolderLocation
write-host "Target Folders Being Moved: " $MoveFolder

#----- define where to move folders ----#
$LocationFolderMove = '\\file location'


#----- define location of log file ----#
$LogFile = ".\logfile.log"
$LogFile = Read-Host "Where would you like to put the log file?"
$LogFile

#---- Define Log Location ----#
$DoesLogFileExist = Test-Path -Path $LogFile

#---- Create The Log File and Put Headers In It ----#
IF($DoesLogFileExist)
    {

        Clear-Content $LogFile
        "Folder_Moved,IsFolderAtOriginalLocation" | Out-File $LogFile 
    }
ELSE
    {
        "Folder_Moved,IsFolderAtOriginalLocation" | Out-File $LogFile 
    }



#----- get folder to move to another location ---#

foreach ($Folder in $MoveFolder)

{
write-host "Folder is: "$Folder


 $FolderToBeDeleted = $Folder


            IF (!(Test-Path -path $LocationFolderMove=)) 
         #    IF ($Folder)   
              {
                  write-host "Moving Folder $Folder" -ForegroundColor "Red"
                  Move-Item -LiteralPath $FolderToBeDeleted -Destination $LocationFolderMove -force
                  $HasMoved = Test-Path -Path $Folder
                  $FolderMoved = $Folder
                  "$FolderMoved,$HasMoved" | Out-File $LogFile -Append 
              }  



}

Write-Host "Folder move cleanup complete. No more folders to move!" -foregroundcolor "Green"
```

Comment: You forgot to post an example `csv` file, that produces the error. I guess, it contains subfolders whose parent folders have already been moved. Or just folders that really do not exist. Just take a closer look to the error message, that you also did not provide! Try also to minimize your example code, that still produces the error. I mean, `Move-Item` moves folders. There is probably no need for us to read 60+ lines to move folders.

Comment: Also, I would strongly advise against using `Read-Host` to get the folder of filepath. Who knows what the user may enter?

Answer (score 1):

Always build your script one step at a time and validate that you are getting back what you'd expect.

For example. Why are you using the same variable for two different purposes?

```
$MoveFolderLocation = '.\Move_Folder_Input.csv'
$MoveFolderLocation = Read-Host "Where is the folder list file?"
```

You are overwriting one with the other, and the last one in wins.

I agree with Theo on that Read-Host thing. My default Dev/Script rule #1 is:

- 'All input is evil until it is fully validated, no matter where it comes
  from.'

So, change that Read-Host to something like.

```
($FileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog -Property @{ 
    InitialDirectory = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('MyDocuments') 
}).ShowDialog() | Out-Null
$FileBrowser.FileName
```

Even with the browser effort, you still need to take into account, files/folders that have spaces, special characters, etc., thus provide code to deal with that.